# How to extract text from a PSD file?

Tags: linux, photoshop, gimp

I need to extract the text from the layers in a photoshop PSD file on linux.  Does anyone know how to do that?  Gimp rasterizes the text and you can't copy and paste it.  Also, note that I do not own the Photoshop program.

Comment: Similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/850899/editing-photoshop-psd-text-layers-programmatically

Comment: Similar? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 29):

Have you tried using vim?

VIM comes with a flag that lets you edit a binary file.

I tried editing a PSD file with:

```
vim -b file.psd
```

This is an example of what I got when editing the file:

> ```
>                             <dict>
>                                     <key>com.apple.print.PageFormat.PMAdjustedPageRect</key>
>                                     <array>
>                                             <real>0.0</real>
>                                             <real>0.0</real>
>                                             <real>576</real>
>                                             <real>734</real>
>                                     </array>
>                                     <key>com.apple.print.ticket.stateFlag</key>
>                                     <integer>0</integer>
>                             </dict>
> ```

Comment: I get some text when doing that, but not all the text comes through that way

Comment: OK, now that I'm on my 10 PSD file, you have to regex two chars to make this work (at least with CS3 PSD format): "^0" to "" (empty) and ^M to "\r" makes it easier to see the text.

Comment: I opened the psd file in Notepad++ and changed to a proper encoding and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 17):

Just released this feature in the NPM package `psd-cli`. Makes it simple to extract text content **without the headache of manually running through the file**...

One-line command install (needs [NodeJS/NPM installed](https://nodejs.org/en/))

`npm install -g psd-cli`

You can then use it by typing in your terminal

`psd myfile.psd -t`

This will create `myfile.txt`, containing all text extracted from each PSD layer with the layer structure attached.

Enjoy !

[npmjs.org package description](https://www.npmjs.com/package/psd-cli)

Comment: Sorry, this didn't work in my case, maybe the file was too large with long layer names (a mess). FYI I got this: `Processing myfile.psd ...
[TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null]`

Comment: I would be happy to debug this if you provide me an example file, and if possible send an issue on Github

Comment: worked great for me, much better than `strings` that didn't work with any utf8 chars it seems

Comment: No need for the `-g` flag (install globally). Simply `npm install psd-cli`, then `./node_modules/.bin/psd myfile.psd -t`. Once you finished, you can delete the `node_modules` directory (and the `package-lock.json` file). No trace.

Answer (score 14):

```
strings FILENAME > temp.txt
```

The file `temp.txt` will contain all the plain text strings from the file, including some additional PSD settings. You'll have to manually search this file for the text you need.

Comment: This tool is excellent. But I had to deal with a very large PSD, which resulted in a never-ending `cat temp.txt` so I used `-d` flag to narrow the amount of text read from the PSD, and `-e S` to tell `strings` tool that the text I wanted was UTF-8 (without this I got messed latin characters). The full command then would be: `strings -d -e S FILENAME > temp.txt`

Answer (score 3):

You can use Photopea, it is not a desktop app, it runs in browser so you do not need to install anything, just open your psd file, and edit, or copy the text like in Photoshop:

https://www.photopea.com/

Answer (score 2):

Visit the internet site http://www.bram.us/2008/10/30/ps_bramustextconvert-psd2txt-and-txt2psd-for-the-masses/. There are two tools to export and import text from psd files. It goes very good!

Comment: I looked, but I didn't see it.  Would you provide a more specific link?

Comment: In case anyone stumbles onto this page, it is here: http://www.bram.us/2008/10/30/ps_bramustextconvert-psd2txt-and-txt2psd-for-the-masses/

Comment: This site's scripts seem to require photoshop, which is ruled out by the user's question.

Comment: Comparison of this option and the omgmog fork here: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8411/is-there-a-simple-way-to-copy-all-text-in-psd-file/36090#36090