# How to extract images from in Photoshop pdf in Linux?

Tags: pdf, photoshop

More and more designers using Photoshop are saving images in pdf format.

I tried Gimp but it doesn't see the layers and other format details.

Any solutions ?

The basic thing I try to do is to get the original images from the pdf with all layers not flatten.

Comment: Odd... PDF isn't exactly a lossless environment for moving photos around, plus losing all the Photoshop metadata on top of that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094104/how-to-extract-text-from-a-psd-file and this http://superuser.com/questions/135351/a-way-to-extract-layer-sets-from-psd-files-without-photoshop