# Gimp: How can I change the text on a layer using Gimp

Tags: gimp

I have PSD file with layer text, I try to modify a layer text in Gimp but I can't find a way to select that text and change it to something else.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Follow this issue: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=151686

Answer (score 30):

Sorry -  GIMP stable does not import the text information for PSD files - which means all it "sees" is pixels.

A little bit over 10 years ago, Adobe completely closed the informations about the PSD file format, and the import/export for this format in GIMP stopped evolving. Some 2-3 years ago, the file format started being documented again - but GIMP is a developer-starved project, with few people working on it, everyone as volunteers. Last year, with the Google Summer of Code project, there was some development in the PSD plug-in, and there is some advances
incorporated into the development version of GIMP.

Looking from 10000 meters, it looks like there is logic in place to open the text layers preserving the text information on the new code. I can't be sure because I have no PSD file to test it here.

If,as a workaround,  you want to findout the typeface names inside the PSD files, in the past I made a simple Python script to print just that - then it is at least possible to recreate the same layer again inside GIMP: https://github.com/jsbueno/psd_print_resources

Comment: Can you advice how to install this script?

Comment: you might all see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094104/how-to-extract-text-from-a-psd-file