# Tough question regarding photoshop, excel and external images

Tags: excel, photoshop, batch-processing

Right, I have a photoshop PSD file, a spreadsheet filled with custom data and a folder full of images. I want a way to create a unique image for each entry in the spreadsheet, where the spread sheet contains data that must populate text elements in the PSD, and references an image which needs to be pasted in to photoshop.

I would normally do this manually, but I need it done for 400+ images, so I am analyzing ways I can automate this, scripted or otherwise.

Do you guys have any ideas? I am desperate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Python will do everything you need.

A related [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850899/editing-photoshop-psd-text-layers-programmatically) links to a description of how to [script PSD editing using Python and Photoshop's COM interface](http://techarttiki.blogspot.com/2008/08/photoshop-scripting-with-python.html).

That post links to the [Adobe Photoshop Scripting Guide](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/PhotoshopScriptingGuide.pdf), which appears to include any and all possible actions within Photoshop - text and layers and everything.

[Python has a CSV reader](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html), as well, so you can just export your spreadsheet as a CSV file and read it into your Python script.

Answer (score 0):

Use Photoshop Variables and Datasets. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-7417a.html