# Manipulating the text of a text layer in a PSD-file on Ubuntu

Tags: python, psd

I can't figure out how to edit a text layer from a PSD-file on Ubuntu using python. `psd-tools` and `pytopsd` don't seem to be able to do this job. As far as I can see there is no possibility to do this without having Photoshop installed on the same OS. I hope someone can prove me wrong.

The solution mentioned in [Editing Photoshop PSD text layers programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850899/editing-photoshop-psd-text-layers-programmatically) relies on the Photoshop COM Interface which is clearly not the solution I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop COM is proprietary and not available under Linux. You should install GIMP (if not present in your linux distro already) and use its command line instead. The GIMP-python library can also fit your needs, check https://www.gimp.org/docs/python/

Comment: Unfortunately he can't use GIMP as it reads PSD text layers as rendered bitmaps therefore it discards any text information!