# Edit textvalue of layer psd with javascript

Tags: javascript, psd

Can i edit text value with javascript or php or other programming language in PSD ?
Anyone know how i can make it please ?
Thanks you for reply

Comment: See this:https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/46632/can-i-modify-text-within-photoshop-files-programmatically

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850899/editing-photoshop-psd-text-layers-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Here some answers [Editing Photoshop PSD text layers programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850899/editing-photoshop-psd-text-layers-programmatically) and [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/46632/can-i-modify-text-within-photoshop-files-programmatically)

In addition, you can use `PSD.js`   NodeJS

https://meltingice.github.io/psd.js/

these are examples

http://meltingice.github.io/psd.js/docs/ and see also [this](http://blog.cipherhack.com/2018/12/30/photoshop-automation-using-javascript/)